# Python - xlwings - How to rename sheet and add value to the name

Tags: python, xlwings

I have a list of Sheets and for each sheet I need to SUM float values from the column A and the SUM outcome should be added to the Sheet name. For example: Sheet1 --> Sheet1 (123). Please advice. Thank you.

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book(filepath)
sheet_names = wb.sheets

for x in sheet_names:
    /missing summary calculation here
    wb.sheets[x].name = wb.sheets[x] + str('123') # ('123') should be the 
    outcome of the SUM so str(SUM)
    
wb.save()
wb.close()
xw.App().quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a simple sheet like the one below:

[image]

I have converted the sheet to a `pandas` dataframe to compute the sum of the first column.  To avoid errors in the summation, I have converted the column to numeric values, returning `NaN` for non-numeric ones. See code below.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

app = xw.App(visible=False) # opens wb without making it visible
wb = xw.Book('Book1.xlsx')
sheet_names = wb.sheets

for x in sheet_names:
    # get pandas dataframe of total sheet
    sheet1 = wb.sheets[x].used_range.value
    df = pd.DataFrame(sheet1)
    # find column A
    colA = df.iloc[:,0]
    # convert values in column A to numerical values, return NaN for non-numeric values
    colA_numeric = pd.to_numeric(colA, errors='coerce')
    # compute sum of colA
    sum_floats = colA_numeric.sum(skipna=True)
    # add sum to sheet name
    wb.sheets[x].name = wb.sheets[x].name + ' ('+str(sum_floats)+')'

wb.save()
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

The result is:

[image]

Note: running the script multiple times will append the sheet name, which will look something like `Sheet 1 (30.0) (30.0)`. You can avoid this by changing the way you obtain the sheet name to be more generic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciate it. Just a quick question, this does not work with float, any idea why? THX

Comment: Hmm.. it should work. The list of numbers I have entered in the first column are all floats. Can you share what error you get?

Comment: Hm, maybe I am adding a wrong column. If I wanna use column name instead of iloc should i just change the code to colA = df[['Column Name']], right? Also, (Sorry to bother you) if I want to apply this to all Sheets apart sheet Data, how the code would look like then? Thank you soo much mate.

Comment: Unpardonable error: sheet_names = wb.sheets, always shoud be: sheets = wb.sheets or similar. Because sheet_names = wb.sheet_names